# Controlling leds with potentiometer and a button on a raspberry pi pico

Tags: led, pi-pico

I am trying to control Leds with a button to change if one is on or off and a potentiometer to control the brightness of the Leds. I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: This might help: https://microcontrollerslab.com/raspberry-pi-pico-pwm-micropython-tutorial/

Comment: You COULD use a potentiometer but if this is what you want just omit the Pico. It would make more sense to use a program.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The Pico has general GPIO you can use to read a button press or release.

The Pico  has an ADC so  you can read the potentiometer voltage.

The Pico has PWM which you can use to vary the brightness  of the LEDs.

Comment: I am having trouble doing both of these at the same time. My button is able to turn on the LES, and separately, the potentiometer can adjust the brightness. However, it cannot do both. When setting up an LED for a button, it has to be 

led = machine.Pin(15, machine.Pin.OUT) 

However, when using a potentiometer for the same LED, it has to be: 

led = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(15))

I cannot have the same LED function with a button and a potentiometer.